# Move files with specific names and containing specific pattern to another directory in Unix

Tags: unix

I have a directory containing files with name starting with timestamp eg 20170102065744.get . Some of these files contain a number as a pattern eg 456787.I need to move only those files whose names match 201701* and have the number pattern 456787 from the original directory to another directory.

The OS is Sun Solaris Unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the correct syntax on solaris os but a linux system you might be able to achieve that using something like this (assuming your current shell prompt location is in that folder containing the files)

```
for i in `find . -type f -name "*201701*" | grep 456787 `; do mv $i move_to_folder/; done
```

Comment: .@Bogdan .Can I do this from command line or do I have to write a shell script?

Comment: You could do it both ways. You can create a simple shell script like
#!/bin/bash
for i in `find . -type f -name "*201701*" | grep 456787 `; do mv $i move_to_folder/; done

Save that script as whatever.sh and execute it via a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using a shell script using grep based on idea suggested by @Bogdan

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 'grep -l 456787 src_dir/201701*`
do
   mv $i destn_dir/
done
```